# Why single sign on config on widfly 10, it can work well on Firefox, Chrome. But It can not work in Microsoft Edge and ie 11?

Tags: jboss7.x

I have a problem concern to configure single sign on in widfly 10. It work well in any other browsers such as Firefox, Chrome.

However It can not work with micosoft edge and IE11. Do you have any idea on this situation?

Comment: How is SSO configured? Is it using OAuth or something else?